# iMac 4k 2017 3ghz - RAM upgrade experience (32G)

Tags: imac, upgrade, memory

I have 4k (21,5") iMac 2017 with 3Ghz CPU. Already using thunderbolt external nvme ssd and now it is time to upgrade the RAM. (Yep, I know what needs to be done, no need to warn me.)

I would like to ask those of you who have already upgraded RAM on this model  to 32G if you have some tips and tricks and if upgrade to 32G is working fine for you.

According to apple this model is upgradable only to 16G (2x8G), unofficially it is suppose to be possible to 32G (2x16G) as models with 3,4Ghz (not sure if motherboard is the same).

Thanks a lot